# Simplifying and reversing an encryption/decryption algorithm in ASM X86 / Python

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, python, encodings

I'm trying to reverse a decoding function in order to produce the function for encoding (for the curious this is a save game for a legacy adventure game which use codes for saving).

So far I have ported the decoding function from ASM X86 to Python and it's working fine.
My problem is I'm not able to reverse the function because I don't understand what the code does with the bitwise operations. Specially the bitwise OR is like voodoo to me.

I'd like some help to simplify/understand the function and reverse it.

My code so far:

```
def load_and_decode_value(text, index, table):
  current_char = ord(text[index])
  return table[current_char]

def text_to_hex(text):
  with open("DECODE_TABLE.bin", mode='rb') as file:
    DECODE_TABLE = file.read()

  decoded = []
  char_index = 0
  text_len = len(text)

  for i in range(0, 5):

    val_0 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_1 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_next_0 = (val_0 * 2048) | (val_1 * 64)
    val_1 = (val_next_0 // 256) & 0xFF
    decoded.append(val_1)

    if i == 4:
      break

    val_2 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_3 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_next_1 = (((val_2 * 2) | val_next_0) * 16777216) | (val_3 * 1048576)
    val_3 = (val_next_1 // 16777216) & 0xFF
    decoded.append(val_3)

    val_4 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_next_2 = val_next_1 | (val_4 * 32768)
    val_4 = (val_next_2 // 65536) & 0xFF
    decoded.append(val_4)

    val_5 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_6 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_next_2 = val_next_2 | (val_5 * 1024)
    val_next_3 = val_next_2 | (val_6 * 32)
    val_6 = (val_next_3 // 256) & 0xFF
    decoded.append(val_6)

    val_7 = load_and_decode_value(text, char_index, DECODE_TABLE)
    char_index += 1
    val_8 = (val_next_3 | val_7) & 0xFF 
    decoded.append(val_8)

  return decoded
```

The content of the DECODE_TABLE.bin file:

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0A 0B 0C 0D 
0E 0F 10 11 01 12 13 01 14 15 00 16 17 18 19 1A FF 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F FF 
FF FF FF FF FF 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 01 12 13 01 14 15 00 16 17 18 
19 1A 1B FF 1C 1D 1E 1F FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
FF FF FF
```

Comment: Have you considered the comment from the duplicate which suggested that this may be [Base32 with this particular alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Crockford's_Base32)?

Answer (score 1):

Tip is Comment every line.

Ex)

```
while i < HARDCODED_LIMIT:
    # Break when text index is out of range
    if text_char_index >= text_len:
        break
    # Load text's ascii number
    eax = ord(text[text_char_index])
    # Increase text index
    text_char_index += 1
    # Load encode array's Nth data (if indexth text's ascii is 116, load 26)
    eax = TEXT_ENCODE_ARRAY[eax]
    # If Nth char is not a character(0~9a~zA~Z), then break
    if eax < 0: # This code is wrong, (0xff < 0) is False
        break
```

Then try to make code in high-level language

```
text: str = "Hello"
text.replace("t", "\x1a")
```

In this level, unusable code is snipped such as

```
esi = eax & 0xFF # eax is smaller than 0xff (eax is Nth data of ENCODE_ARRAY.bin), so this code is same as esi = eax
```

---

Change bitwise operator to human friendly operator

```
esi = esi << 0xB # This could be
esi = esi * 2048 # and, this could be
esi *= 2048
```

---

Try to change common function to def func1()

I think, it seems that the above is repeated

Just make a function code and fill in the changing part with parameters

Then you can read it easily, you can change it to asm code, make decode function, make decode asm code.

PS. If you don't understand bitwise operators, leave them as bitwise operator.

Comment: Hi and thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have rewritten the function based on your comments. You can see it in first post. Can you explain how to reverse it ?